# Db4o returing cached object

Tags: java, db4o

I am using embeddable version of db4o 8.1. The issue is when I retrieve an object and just call set of a property, it seems to be persisting the value in cache and subsequent retrieval gives me the same reference even when I try to retrieve by ID.

The following code is used to retrieve the object from db.

```
public Customer retrieveCustomer(final String id) {
    ObjectContainer db = getDataSource();
    Customer customer = null;
    try {
        List<Customer> result = db.query(new Predicate<Customer>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public boolean match(Customer pilot) {
                return pilot.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(id);
            }
        });
        if (result.size() > 0) {
            customer = result.get(0);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Internal db failed to retrieve the object.", e);
    }
    return customer;
}
```

And somewhere in code I do setName("xyz"); from original value of "abc" and I don't do commit anywhere.

```
customer.setName("xyz"); // no commit or store
```

Everything is fine here but when the object is retrieved again from db it gives me xyz instead of "abc" as i didn't store or commit the previous object.

When I restart the server ( close and open the db ) the old value is restored

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty common mistake for db4o newcomers :)

The problem is that, once retrieved in a session, db4o will keep a reference to the object (that's how it figure it out whenever a Store() is indeed a store or an update); so the second time you fetch the object from db, db4o will find the cached one and return it (you can read more about this, and other concepts, [here](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/basics/identity_concept.htm)).

The solution? Depends on your needs, but you could:

- Make a clone of the returned object and update this clone
- [Open multiple sessions](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/client-server/embedded.htm) with the database (db4o has some optimizations for embedded clients).

If you are new to db4o, I recommend [reading this documentation](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/).

Comment: Thanks Vagaus this solves my query and is a MUST know for anyone working with DB4o :)